# Problems with navbar and image centering

Tags: html, css

As part of a school project I am trying to create my first webpage. I am however stuck on this issue where my navigation bar moves down the page when I place a logo in the top bar and center it. I wonder if anyone could help?

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3k65c20u/

Here is my code:

```css
#header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
#top-bar {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
//Top Navigation Bar//
 .navigation-bar {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
img.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 210px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
}
.navigation-bar li a {
  color: gray;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-right: 16px;
}
.navigation-bar li:first-child {
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: #C00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="feistybite.css">
  <div id="header">


    <div id="top-bar"></div>





    <div class="navigation-bar">
      <img src="strikerlogo.png" class="center">


      <div id="navigation-container" class="cf">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Miten se toimii</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Osta</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Tarina</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Meistä</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Uutisia</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what design you want achieve, but i just changed the navigation bar position to relative, and the image to absolute, so... set left to 50% and using the CSS property `transform: translateX(-50%);` the image is finally centered

https://jsfiddle.net/3k65c20u/1/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `padding: 210px` at the `.navigation-bar ul` rule!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change css in `ul` to, removing `padding:210px;`

```
.navigation-bar ul   {
    margin: 0px;
  text-align:center;
}
```